# Inner join on array column in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, join, array, catalogs

In Postgres **9.4**, I'm trying to pull the names of all columns that are involved in a `UNIQUE` constraint for a given table in Postgres.

It looks like the names of such columns are contained in `pg_constraint`. According to [the docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-constraint.html), the column relevant to my problem is called `conkey`, which happens to be an array of `int`s.

The point is, the query I've come up with gives me the wrong results, and I'm pretty sure it's because I'm joining on `conkey` in the wrong way. The query is as follows:

```
SELECT
    pg_attribute.attname,
    pg_constraint.*
FROM
    pg_attribute
INNER JOIN pg_constraint 
        ON pg_attribute.attnum = ANY (pg_constraint.conkey)
WHERE pg_constraint.conrelid = (
    SELECT
        oid
    FROM
        pg_class
    WHERE
        relname LIKE 'test_table'
)
AND pg_constraint.contype = 'u'; -- to filter out non-unique constraints
```

Here's a table DDL for a quick repro:

```
CREATE TABLE "test_table" (
"date" date DEFAULT now() NOT NULL,
"foo" varchar COLLATE "default" NOT NULL
CONSTRAINT "test_table_foo_key" UNIQUE ("foo")
)
WITH (OIDS=FALSE);

ALTER TABLE "test_table" OWNER TO "postgres";
```

Now, can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Is there an easier way to get the information I want altogether?

I'm trying to retrieve the names of constrained table because the app I'm writing needs to work around the current lack of `UPSERT` in Postgres. The idea is to do the insert-or-update with a CTE, but since I don't know what the constrained columns are beforehand, I need to do this bit of introspection.

Comment: You might want to have a look at the [auto_merge](https://github.com/waveform80/oliphant/blob/master/merge/merge--0.1.sql#L331) function in the suite I've been building; it sounds like it a does a lot of what you want (constructing an upsert-style CTE in SQL - although it explicitly doesn't deal with the repetition required by a true upsert solution).It's still a work in progress, but that bit is pretty much done ([docs](http://oliphant.readthedocs.org/en/latest/merge.html) are still incomplete though)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You half miss the connection between the two tables.  The `...relid` columns must match, too:

```
SELECT attname, c.* 
  FROM pg_attribute a 
  JOIN pg_constraint c 
    ON attrelid = conrelid -- this was missing
   AND attnum = ANY (conkey) 
 WHERE attrelid = 'test_table'::regclass;
```

Comment: Aaaaand here's a virtual pint of beer for you. Thank you so much, that was exactly what I was doing wrong.

Comment: Also, thanks for the `regclass::oid` trick that saves me a subselect.

Comment: `WHERE attrelid = 'test_table'::regclass` will do, since `regclass` already *is* an `oid` alias. [A special one.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-oid.html)